# No public or shared folder discovery on successful VPN connection

Tags: networking, vpn

Here is my problem:

I have successfully created a VPN server on Windows 10 Pro, forwarded the necessary port (TCP and UDP) and I can connect from another Windows 10 Pro computer (through Internet). Both computers belong to WORKGOUP.

The problem is that the client computer cannot access or discover the remote network, like public and shared folders, but I can browse the Internet.

In advanced sharing settings, I have tried turning everything to "on", for public and private networks, I even tried turning off the firewall on the host computer but nothing works.

I have tried to access the folders using

`\\\servers.ip.address.here\Users\Public` and `\\\servername\Users\Public`

But nothing works, if I right-click "Map a network drive" and say "Browse" the host computer is not listed there or anywhere else.

I am probably making a simple mistake (it usually is) but the this article show in a concise manner how I created the VPN connection, the article is for Windows 8 but it's virtually identical on Windows 10:

http://www.topnettricks.com/how-to-set-up-a-simple-vpn-in-windows-8/

I might also add that I couldn't access the internet through the VPN until I added these settings to the connection (the server/host has a static local IP of 192.168.0.115), here is a screenshot:

Screenshot of: Incoming IP Properties, IP address assignment:

[image]

I hope someone can point out my mistake here...

Comment: To keep it short and simple: You have a layer 3 VPN. Resource discovery only works in your local broadcast domain. Connecting via IP should work, however. A UNC path starts with two backslashes: `\\host\resource`.

Comment: @DanielB:  The missing extra backslash is now fixed, it was a mistake in my post.  Are you saying that this can't be done what I was trying?  How can I access remote files with VPN?